# Is it safe to use 1/4 inch tempered glass for dining table top?

Tags: glass, table

I am planning to buy a [tempered glass](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Peak-Aluminum-Railing-66-in-x-36-5-16-in-x-1-4-in-Tempered-Glass-Panel-50895/203683313). it is 66*36*1/4 inch thick. I am planning to put it on a 0.25 inch thick*48 inch*36 inch  metal table that I have. The table is 36 inch high. There wont be any center support.

I have added image of my table. As you can see it has a metal rectangle frame that is 0.25 inch thick

Do you think it is a safe design?

[image]

Comment: That's not suitable for a dining table with such a large span, and which could potentially have 20-30 lbs. of dishes, beverages, and elbows on it. Half inch, maybe.

Comment: I don't know of the strength and I'd say it's probably going to come down to your call on what to do. But, one of the Q&A for that product listed says that its required to withstand up to 200 lbs when used as intended for railing.

Comment: I have added an image of my table. Please take a look and let me know your opinion

Comment: I have a commercially purchased glass-top coffee table where the largest unsupported span is 32", and it uses 3/8" thick glass. 1/4" seems a little thin for a span of your size, but I don't have any data to back it up. If you're planning on removing the wood top of your table, keep in mind that the wood top is likely part of the structure and helps keep the table frame solid, it may not be very strong with the wood removed unless the glass is solidly attached (but then you're relying on the glass itself to provide structural integrity).

Comment: Half inch would probably be OK. There's an online glass load calculator [here.](http://www.dullesglassandmirror.com/glass-shelf-weight-load-calculator.aspx)  It spits out 240 pounds for 1/4", which is not nearly enough for a table (think about a person sitting or leaning on it).

Comment: I think Johnny is making a really good point. It appears the wood is part of the structure. It's preventing the frame from twisting. I don't think that frame is suitable for a top that isn't firmly attached.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not! Unsupported ends & center is a big no-no. Support means that it won't bend AT ALL. Why? Because glass doesn't bend...for long.

Comment: I have added an image of my table. Please take a look and let me know your opinion

Comment: Yeah, sorry it's just not a good idea. Even those corner braces that are holding the current top on would be a problem for glass as they stand proud of the perimeter frame or vice versa (I can't really tell which sits on which). Even if you got glass that matches the current top's dimensions, the center would be a trampoline for a few seconds. Doing glass the size of the current top & putting it on top of the current top is fine, that's done everywhere. Why not just go with wood or wood-like stuff atop the current top? You initial plan is fine, just not for glass.